# Firebase authentication per day quota

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

The Firebase pricing plan shows the SMS daily limit is 10.

[image]

But Firebase Authentication shows an SMS quota of 50/day.

[image]

Why Firebase Authentication is showing a different quota? and after billing (it was needed for map service) it's still showing the same quota remainder.

Comment: You should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly for questions about billing and limits.